# bash eval "echo 'string' >> file" statement with literal quotes

Tags: bash, shell, eval, quotes

I'm new to shell scripting. I've started using terminal a lot for SASS and git and want a simple script to make creating shortcuts easy.

```
function ma {
    cmd="echo alias $1='$2' >> ~/.bash_profile";
    cmd=${cmd/'$pwd'/$(pwd)};
    eval $cmd;
    echo $cmd;
}
```

The problem is that the single-quotes are not written to .bash_profile.

In example `ma mycd '$pwd'`, the echo'd version is correct:

`echo alias mycd='cd /current/working/directory' >> ~/.bash_profile`

but this is written to the file:

`alias mycd=cd /current/working/directory`

I have tried maybe 50 permutations of this, trying to get the right combination of single and double quotes, and escaped quote, in the string or in the eval statement. How can I make `eval` keep those single quotes, or what should I use instead? Thanks!

Comment: Because I find this so useful, I thought I would share my updated version, which reloads the profile so the new alias is available for immediate use: 
`function ma {
 cmd="echo \"alias $1='$2'\" >> ~/.bash_profile";
 cmd=${cmd/'$pwd'/$(pwd)};
 eval $cmd;
 echo $cmd;
 source ~/.bash_profile;
 echo 'Ready to go';
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 cmd="echo \"alias $1='$2'\" >> ~/.bash_profile";
```

Comment: Yes! Ha, I had just finally tried that myself. :) SO is saying I can't accept the answer, but I'll return and try again later. Cheers.